# How to get absolute value from NSDateComponents

Tags: objective-c

I want to take absolute value from NSDateComponents.

```
<NSDateComponents: 0x600000477c80>
Calendar Year: -1
```

I tried the following way.But I did not get the exact value.How can i get the value 1 from the components.

```
    NSDate *startDate = [formatter dateFromString:birthDate];
    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear
                                                        fromDate:startDate
                                                          toDate:today
                                                         options:0];

    NSInteger year = [components year];
```

Comment: What is the issue? You are getting wrong `year`?

Comment: @TheTiger.Yes I am getting wrong "Year"

Comment: How do you get the `components` object?

Comment: I updated my question.Please check it

Comment: What is the value of `birthDate` and try using `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]`

Comment: What you want exactly? Because components returns the difference between two dates in respective of the selected unit, so in your case it will returns years between `birthDate` and `today` not only year = 1.

Comment: `NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger year = [components year];` year will have the current year value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get difference of the dates in the years, then you have to use method : `calendar: fromDate: toDate:`

And if you want to get only year from the date, then you have to use this method : `calendar: fromDate:`.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSString *birthDate = @"04/06/1984 01:45:20";
NSDate *startDate = [formatter dateFromString:birthDate];
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

//NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:startDate toDate:today options:0];  //Option 1
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:startDate];  // Option 2

NSInteger year = [components year];
NSLog(@"Years : %ld", year);
```

If you use method of option 1, then it will print `Years : 35`.

And if you use method of option 2, then it will give `Years : 1984`.